# Displaying NSArray in UITableView (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I want to display in UITableView array like:

```
(
    1,
        {
        date = 1351876762;
        ncom = 0;
        nid = 11739814;
        "read_ncom" = 0;
        text = "<div class=\"wikiText\"><!--4-->New note text </div>";
        title = lol;
        uid = 3795852;
    }
)
```

Cells should have a label with "title" from this array.
How can I make that?

P.S.:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *textCell = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.textLabel.text = textCell;
    return cell;
}
```

returns signal SIGABRT.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question but your commented out line should be more `cell.textlabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ncom"]];` you do not need the `[NSString stringwithFormat:];` And you can put the `textCell` straight into the `cell.textLabel.text` no need for `NSString *textCell`

Comment: print your array into console

Comment: Is the `1` the array index or a dictionary key?

Comment: Is `title = lol;` a string? like everything else.

Comment: `1` is a dictionary key. `title=lol;` is a string

Comment: Where has you array been initialized and filled? Can you do `NSLog(@"%@", arrayName);` and get anything. Put just before `textCell`

Comment: Right so you will a structure of `0 ( 1 {date, ncom, nid, ... } )` and not how you have done it.

Comment: `2012-11-05 13:49:40.883 iVK[847:c07] (
    1,
        {
        date = 1351876762;
        ncom = 0;
        nid = 11739814;
        "read_ncom" = 0;
        text = "<div class=\"wikiText\"><!--4-->New note text </div>";
        title = lol;
        uid = 3795852;
    }
)`

Comment: Where do you add this dictionary object to your array? If this is an array.

Comment: in ViewController.h: `NSArray *array;`

Comment: In viewDidLoad: `NSDictionary* parsedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:response
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];
    
    array = [parsedDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];`

Comment: `[[[array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"1"] objectForKey:@"title"];` ignore `indexPath.row` at this time. What does it do? or even just `[array objectAtIndex:0];` do it in stages up to the final one.

Comment: SIGABRT, `2012-11-05 13:55:12.386 iVK[890:c07] -[__NSCFNumber objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x717e980
2012-11-05 13:55:12.387 iVK[890:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x717e980'`

Comment: Do it in stages and `NSLog` everything so you can see where it is going wrong. I think your structure is wrong that is if it is the same as what you have shown. Don't worry about the crash as long as you can see your `NSLog`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found the solution. `NSString *textCell = [[array objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"title"];`

Comment: thanks to another comment I know where your going wrong. You are printing your array out into more then one cell correct? The `indexPath.row` starts at `0` What is at `0` in your array? or after make sure there is an object for every indexPath.row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]

Your array seems to be weird. Try following and let me know the result.

```
NSString *textCell = [[array objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Comment: Then signal SIGABRT at line textCell = [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"1"] objectForKey:@"title"];

Comment: Can you please correct your array structure? How exactly it looks like?

Comment: Yah because you have array count=2 but first index doesn't make any sense! it's just integer 1! That's why I said your array is weird. You might need workout more, what you looking for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You should have cell with identifier "Cell" in your table (if you have storyboard) or create this cell manually

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Then signal SIGABRT at line     NSString *textCell = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text  = [[array objectAtIndex:1] objectforkey:@"title"];
```

try the above code

Comment: Then signal SIGABRT at line    cell.textLabel.text  = [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"1"] objectForKey:@"title"];

Answer (score -1):

Replace this :

```
NSString *textCell = [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"1"]objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Comment: Then signal SIGABRT at this line